# Conjecture about closeness of points in an arbitrary set on the circular unit interval

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I am trying to prove a statement over $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ (the circular unit interval $[0,1]$ with endpoints joined) for some finite set $P$ of n points.

Conjecture: Picking $p\in P$ randomly, the expected number of points in $P\cap (p-d,p+d)$ is at least $n(2d).$

Equivalently, $\#\{i,j : |p_i-p_j| < d\} \geq n^2(2d).$

I think measure theory is the tool to help me show this (especially seeing as it is foundational in probability theory), but I do not see how to prove this. This also feels like a more general result about how the uniform pdf is the most spread out measure available.

My first attempt is to compute the expected number of points in such an interval using Lebesgue measure $\mu$ and find a comparison to the normalized counting measure/pdf $m$ generated by our finite points (measure of an interval is the number of points it contains divide $|P|$).

$$\int \int_{p-d}^{p+d} dm d\!\!\:\mu(p)
= \int \int_{p-d}^{p+d} dm(p) d\!\!\:\mu
= \int 2d d\!\!\:\mu = 2d.$$

But I'm struggling to convert this into a proof for
$$\int \int_{p-d}^{p+d} dmdm(p) \geq \int \int_{p-d}^{p+d} dmd\!\!\:\mu(p) = 2d.$$
especially because I expect this will be an inequality (a bunch of points together will give about 1 whereas the points spread apart will give $2d$).

Notation or definitional errors may be present because I'm pretty new to measure theory.

Comment: What do you mean by $2|P|d$ ?

Comment: It's hard to figure out what you really want. If you deal with uniform distribution over the circle, it is advisable to use adapted tools like Fourier (probabilistic version: characteristic function).

Comment: Why don't you answer my question ?

Comment: @JeanMarie By that I mean the number of points in the finite set $|P|$ times the distance $2d.$ Thank you for the characteristic functions hint! That makes it much much easier to handle these integral bounds than what I was doing before. Edit: whoops, I should have said indicator function; I will look into using a characteristic function, though

Answer (score 0):

As stated, your conjecture is incorrect. If I’m understanding correctly, you have the interval $[0,1]$ with the endpoints identified to get a circle. You have sampled $P = \{p_1, \cdots, p_n \}$ independently uniformly from $[0,1]$. For a fixed $d > 0$ and $p_j \in P$, you want to compute $\mathbb{E} \big ( \# \{i : |p_j - p_i| < d \} \big )$. If this is the correct understanding of your question, you don’t really need any measure theory. Just basic probability.

Fix some $i \neq j$. It is easy to see that $\mathbb{P}[|p_i - p_j| < d] = \min \{2d, 1\}$. Denote this quantity by $q$. Since the $p_i$ are sampled independently, it easily follows that $\# \{i : |p_j - p_i| < d \}$ is distributed as $1 + \text{Bin}(n-1, q)$. The extra $+1$ and the $n-1$ come from the fact that $|p_i - p_i| = 0$ no matter what. Since the expectation of the binomial part is given by $(n-1)q$, it follows that:
$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E} \big ( \# \{i : |p_j - p_i| < d \} \big ) &= 1 + (n-1)q \\ &= 1 + 2(n-1)d \quad \text{ if $d \leq \frac{1}{2}$} \end{align*} $$
This is different from the quantity you speculated. Your result does work as a limit though, in a sense. If we consider this quantity $P(n) := 1 + 2(n-1)d$, we see that:
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{P(n)}{n} = 2d$$
This is just a specific instance of the Glivenko-Cantelli Theorem ([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glivenko–Cantelli_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glivenko%E2%80%93Cantelli_theorem))

Comment: Oh that isn't what I'm trying to ask, sorry for being unclear. $P$ is a selection of $n$ points made in advance, and I want to show $\#\{i,j : |p_i-p_j|<d\} \geq n^2(2d)$

Comment: You need to make that much more clear. To quote from your post, “ I am trying to prove that over $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{N}$,  (the circular unit interval) that, for some finite set of points $P$ picking $p \in P$, randomly, the expected number of points in $(p-d, p + d)$ is $2|P|d$.”

Comment: I've edited the question and I hope it clears up better what I'm asking